# Not able to get font-face working

Tags: css, font-face

I'm trying to use `@font-face`, but I'm not being very successfull.
Up till now, I've been using Google fonts:

```
// HTML header
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

//CSS
#leftSection nav { 
  font-family: "Cuprum", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Then I downloaded the fonts and tried using `font-face`:

This is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cuprum';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  src: url('cuprum.eot?') format('eot'), 
       url('cuprum.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('cuprum.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('cuprum.svg#Cuprum') format('svg');
}


#leftSection nav { 
  font-family: "Cuprum", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The fonts are located in the same folder as the CSS.

I've looked at, and tested oteher solutions, but I'm still not able to get it wokring.

I'm testing with the following browsers: FF7, IE8

**Update**
I've added `font-size: 0.5em;` This should at least change the font size. But that's not happening either. So I'm guessing the entire `@font-face` is ignored.

Comment: Do you have a link in the header to your CSS file? The link you have there is just to the Google Font API.

Comment: Yes, the CSS files loads fine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using the Font Squirrel generator?  Just upload the font and it will do everything for you, it's real simple.

Here is the link:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: That's where I got my fonts in the first place :)

Comment: FontSquirrel is great - it can give you all the CSS you need. It also comes with sample code and converts fonts to all the types you'll need - SVG, WOFF, EOT and TTF.

Comment: I know. I tested using the example CSS, but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Steven are you done with this?
Why dont you try this out.

insert this inside your css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Cuprum';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Cuprum'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/cuprum/v1/sp1_LTSOMWWV0K5VTuZzvQ.woff') format('woff');
}

#leftSection nav { 
font-family: Cuprum, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

i hope it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try it without the quotes around `"Cuprum"`.

```
#leftSection nav { 
  font-family: Cuprum, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Also, there is sometime an issue if you/the user have that font installed locally.

To get around that, you can set a fake `local` reference.

See [Paul Irish's Bulletproof @font-face syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

**EDIT**

Two other things you might try:

1. change the font name to lowercase, `cuprum`.
2. Remove the following from the declaration:

   ```
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   font-size: 0.5em;
   ```

Comment: Jason Gennaro, I've tried without the quotes as well, still not working.

Comment: I've made a couple more suggestions @Steven.  See if those help.

Comment: Maybe there was a "bad" generation when you ran it through FontSquirrel.  What about running the generation over again?